# Add quantity of variations together and show it to parent quantity field Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On my site i am using woocommerce and i am importing products from XML using WP ALL IMPORT.
i have the problem that the parent product has not any quantity or it is taking the quantity of the first variation.

I would like to add all the variation's quantity together and show it to the parent quantity field of the product.
For example.
One product has 3 Variations. Variation 1 has quantity 10, variation 2 has quantity 5 and variation 3 has quantity 20. If we add them together we will have 35 quantity of all variations. I need that amount to show it on the parent's quantity field. With that way i can order the items on my shop more easily and i could see how many quantity in total i have.

Now i am opening every time the variations to check that.

I contacted WP ALL IMPORT and they said that, that is possible with custom coding on it.
WP ALL IMPORT's Plugin has a functions editor field for custom coding that can be used when importing products

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me: shouldn't you compute the parent product's quantity dynamically instead? Then when you sell one of the variations you don't need to update the product parent's quantity too, just the variation you sold. Unless WooCommerce does that for you automatically?

Comment: i didnt understand you correctly.. like i said i need the amount of product variation's stock to be shown in the parent stock